# Plots in function documentation do not display correctly

Tags: r, documentation, raster, roxygen2, pkgdown

I am writing an R-package and its documentation using `roxygen2` to document my functions and `pkgdown` to create a github page.

The package is about rasters, so I have included some raster plot in the examples of my function documentation.

When the examples run in the console everything looks fine. When they run via the `pkgdown` package (using `build_reference()` or `build_site()`) the plot display on the github changes.

This is the correct plot

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(matrix(1:49, nrow = 7, byrow = TRUE))
plot(r)
text(r)
```

[image: correct plot]

This is how the plot is rendered on the github page in the reference section.

[image: wrong plot]

Note that if the same plots are included in a vignette and not in the documentation they are rendered just fine.

I am a bit at a lost here. Do you have any suggestion on why this is happening and how can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this behavior is owed to the fact the raster plot fix the aspect ration to 1 while the `text` function plots on the entire plotting area.

I still do not understand why things are fine in the vignettes and not in the documentation but a workaround is to set the argument `asp = NA`.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(matrix(1:49, nrow = 7, byrow = TRUE))
plot(r, asp=NA)
text(r)
```

[image]

With this setting the plot is showed fine everywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pkgdown resets the `par`s after each plot. I think this may not be an issue if you use `terra` instead of `raster` --- and that would be a much better choice anyway if you are developing a new package.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your answer. I'll try to switch to `terra` as you suggested. However the package has been in development for quite some time and I am afraid it'll take quite some time to change raster for terra.

Comment: ~80% of the interface is the same. See the bottom of `?terra` for differences with `raster`